# How is the association between a seed and its addresses implemented?

Tags: seed, address

For example, how can a wallet determine what addresses correspond to a given seed (before and after a snapshot)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An **address** is generated from a [**private key**](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/584/10).

A **private key** is generated from any random **81 trytes** (e.g. a **seed**)

> If you want to know how this *generating* works in detail, you should look at the implementations in the GitHub. (e.g. [here in PyOTA](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.py/blob/master/iota/crypto/addresses.py)) It's basically just a lot of Kerl/Curl hashing.

Since we want to create more than 1 **private key** from a **seed**, we do this:

- **private key 0** is generated from **seed**
- **private key 1** is generated from **seed + 1**
- **private key 2** is generated from **seed + 2**
- **private key 3** is generated from **seed + 3**
- ...

Since the **seed** consists of trytes, it's basically just a **number in ternary format**, so we can add to it.

---

If you already used the first 10 addresses of your seed, you could theoretically use **seed + 10** as your **new seed** and you would still see your total balance in a wallet.

I made [a program](https://github.com/za-uz/iota-address-finder) that does exactly that. It trims your seed so that your used addresses aren't generated anymore when you log in to a wallet.

([Here](https://github.com/za-uz/iota-address-finder/blob/master/address_finder.py#L67) is the part where I add a number to a seed.)

Comment: 1. In a wallet, should there be the ability to generate a new address at a user's request or should a new address be generated automatically under certain circumstances (e.g., after an old address has been used as the input of some transaction)?

Comment: 2. Should a wallet store or in some way keep track of all the addresses it has generated? Also, should it mostly ignore the “used” addresses and use only the “active” one(s) in a meaningful way?

Comment: 3. And why do they say that addresses should be regenerated in a wallet after a snapshot? Isn’t it so that a wallet should constantly have all the required info about its addresses, why does a snapshot require it to take some extra steps to reobtain such info?

Comment: 1. both have advantages and disadvantages, depends on circumstances and opinion

Comment: 2. definitely keep track of **spent addresses** and never use them again (for security reasons) or do something like the current GUI Wallet: never use leading and empty addresses of a seed

Comment: 3. would be a great [new question](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: By the way, I've also found some answers to questions 2 and 3 [here](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/929/address-re-use-and-snapshot?) and [here](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/658/how-many-addresses-do-i-have-to-reattach-after-a-snapshot?).